# How to rewrite .htaccess external link php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have the following link

```
www.site.com/img.php?=http://external.link/image.jpg
```

what should look like

```
www.site.com/img/image.jpg
```

Can I make a rule with htacces to override the wrong link?
without a redirect being seen in the url bar

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

You just have to put the code below in your `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^img/([a-z0-9_-.]+)/?$ img.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

And then you can implement the following piece of code in your `img.php` page

```
if ( isset($_GET['p']) ) {
    printf(
        "<img src=\"http://external.link/%s\" alt=\"\">", 
        htmlspecialchars($_GET['p'])
    );
}
```